# What is Nenesha's Heart of Gaea for?

Tags: ar-tonelico

When the party goes after Laude who went into the Moon Culvert with Reisha they come across another Heart of Gaea. Luca then seems to switch to Nenesha with her saying that the Heart of Gaea is her body.

Considering that Nenesha said it was her that would mean this wouldn't be a Heart of Gaea Frelia may have made to create the land of Metafalss, so what is Nenesha's Heart of Gaea for? and why was it even created as in Infel's diary she wrote that the Divine Messenger killed Nenesha

Answer (score 1):

Nenesha's soul was partially transmigrated into a Heart of the Land because despite Metafalica failing, the EXEC part of it was fully executed regardless because Raki just killed her and that didn't keep the song from fully manifesting its effects. (ref: Ar tonelico II Setting Encyclopedia, History section)

And Frelia couldn't even have created a Heart of the Land because her Tower was made by making the particles in the air vibrate to transform them into the materials that make up the Tower, which is an inert land made entirely from metal (ref: Ar tonelico III Setting Encyclopedia, Wave Theory section). A Heart of the Land proper creates a fully living land and requires far more complex processes and facilities for its creation.

Comment: So why was it in the Moon Culvert? to my understanding the Moon Culvert is deep inside the tower and seems to be a strange place for the core of new land to appear

Comment: Because it wasn't made to create a new land and ended up appearing by accident: it first appeared over Metafalss' skies. Infel just hid it in the Culvert so no one could ever take it away while she tried to come up with methods to contact Nenesha's soul inside the Heart, and the one she ended developing was Hibernation once she learned that bringing Nenesha back to life was impossible because her body had perished by the time she discovered how to take her soul out from the Heart.